# [kinetic] joint_state_publisher doesn't run

Tags: ros, urdf, joint-state-publisher, qt5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a problem while lunching *joint_state_publisher* with any urdf file in ROS Kinetic and ubuntu 16.04

it crashes due to a missing library, I made sure that the library exists and is included in the path, but still the same problem

Here's the console output when I try to lunch the rrbot example:

```
$ roslaunch rrbot_description rrbot_rviz.launch
... logging to /home/amine/.ros/log/4d3d7f60-81f3-11e7-b988-303a643c719d/roslaunch-Destructor-26505.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://Destructor:37085/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /joint_state_publisher/use_gui: True
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.7

NODES
  /
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[joint_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [26526]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [26527]
process[rviz-3]: started with pid [26528]
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
[joint_state_publisher-1] process has died [pid 26526, exit code -6, cmd /home/amine/catkin_ws/src/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher __name:=joint_state_publisher __log:=/home/amine/.ros/log/4d3d7f60-81f3-11e7-b988-303a643c719d/joint_state_publisher-1.log].
log file: /home/amine/.ros/log/4d3d7f60-81f3-11e7-b988-303a643c719d/joint_state_publisher-1*.log
```

Here is the output of roswtf:

```
$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
ERROR: connection refused to [http://Destructor:46872/]
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 3 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /joint_state_publisher:
   * /clock
 * /robot_state_publisher:
   * /joint_states
   * /clock
 * /rviz:
   * /rrbot/laser/scan
   * /clock

WARNING These nodes have died:
 * joint_state_publisher-1

WARNING No tf messages

Found 4 error(s).

ERROR /use_simtime is set but no publisher of /clock is present
ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /joint_state_publisher

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /joint_state_publisher->/rosout (/rosout)

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/joint_state_publisher/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/joint_state_publisher/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://Destructor:36562]
 * service [/joint_state_publisher/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/joint_state_publisher/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://Destructor:36562]
```

It seems clear that it's crashing due to missing xcb plugin,

I made sure `libxcb.so` and `libXi.so` are available in the path, I also made sur the variables `QT_PLUGINS_PATH` and `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH` are pointing to the correct path, and still the same problem.

I'm using:

```
ubuntu 16.04 
conda 4.3.23 (64-bits)
python 2.7
qt 5.6.2 (installed using anaconda)
libxcb-1.12-1
```

I also installed Qt 5.7 but it's still not working

Any ideas to help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268906/%5Bkinetic%5D-joint_state_publisher-doesn%27t-run/) by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2017-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-16**:
Does it work if you use the platform Python?

**Comment by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) on 2017-08-16**:
I got the same problem with the built-in Python of ubuntu, because 'pyqt' was installed in the pkg folder of anaconda. So I removed all the conda packages and cleared the cache. Then, I reinstalled 'pyqt' and 'qt' again, and it works fine now.
I guess the old packages was corrupted. Thanks @gvdhoorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was caused by a problem in the source package of Qt in anaconda.

I solved the problem by removing the conda packages and clearing the cache:

```
conda remove pyqt
conda remove qt5
conda clean --all
```

Then I reinstalled PyQt and Qt from a different source, and it works fine:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyqt 
conda install pyqt
conda install -c anaconda qt
```

Make sure to set these two variables in *.bashrc*:

```
export QT_PLUGINS_PATH=/path/to/qt_plugins_folder
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/path/to/qt_plugins_folder/platforms
```

And that the *libxcb.so* library is located in one of the specified paths.

---

Originally posted by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) with karma: 229 on 2017-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0